# MYSQL Entity framework connector in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have been trying to get the Entity Framework to work in my web application in C# using MySQL,I looked at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html but couldn't figure out what is the right one?can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: Have you tried the `MySql.Data.Entity` nuget package?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Connector/Net]
Look at the documentation here
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html